# How create a custom domain on Oracle cloud free tier?

Tags: oracle-apex

Is there a direct option to have a custom domain on Oracle cloud free tier (the always free options)?
There are threads talked about accomplishing that through installing a compute instance and installing a web server but it was at year 2017. So, I thought there could be a better solution now.

Comment: I'm also struggling to find at least a sub-domain name :/

Comment: Eslam did you solve?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the VM instance ( Compute > Instances > Instance details), under "Primary VNIC" you should be able to see the instance **Subnet**.

Clck on it to open subnet details, and there you will see subnet's DNS name:
(DNS Domain Name).

Each instance's DNS name should be:

```
Instance FQDN: <hostname>.<subnet-DNS-label>.<VCN-DNS-label>.oraclevcn.com
```

Source & more details: https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Network/Concepts/dns.htm

Answer (score -1):

Please see:

[Free Oracle Cloud: Custom Domain Name (URL) with your own ORDS on the Webserver](http://dgielis.blogspot.com/2020/08/free-oracle-cloud-custom-domain-name.html)

[Introducing Vanity URLs for APEX and ORDS on Oracle Autonomous Database](https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/post/introducing-vanity-urls-on-adb)

Comment: Links to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Thanks but that are the old ways I referred to in my question.

Comment: Vanity URLs was introduced in 2021, how come this is old way?

Comment: Check date at the beginning of the page https://dgielis.blogspot.com/2019/12/free-oracle-cloud-17-configure-domain.html

Comment: And in a writing in 2017 he explained how to do so after setting up a web server on a compute instance.

Comment: Please see the second blog post: https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/post/introducing-vanity-urls-on-adb

Comment: Answers with only links are discouraged. Can you answer the question please?